# What should I know before shifting from Django to Wagtail

Tags: python, django, web, content-management-system, wagtail

I am python programmer ,I know how django works but I'm trying to move to Wagtail.

I seem not to understand about how Wagtail works , it mixes Models with templates and I also find out that it doesn't use any views ,this goes against how django works.

Can you please explain to me what is a Wagtail Page exactly. I know its sort of a model but I don't seem to understand how it works.

I would also like to know how do I get to use Wagtail Pages to render different data depending on data in the database lets say images of Users in the database.

Also ,do I have to create a Page for everything eg If I want to create a User Model or Profile Model ,does it have to be a Page also.

Please Help.

I tried to actually to use Wagtail docs to create a web app but I don't seem to be in control .Wagtail doesn't have an views so i don't know how i can handle the requests in my own way then send the response of my own ,lets say JSON data.

Comment: Doubt you'll get the answer you want here, you should read the docs for Wagtail and watch examples.

Comment: If you want to build a traditional web app and have control over things like the request and response formats, why are you using a CMS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display items from a database table on a Wagtail page, I suggest:

- Add to the [context of a page](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.models.Page.get_context).  You do this just like you would in a Django class-based view by overriding `get_context()`.
- Render the context item(s) in the template that you've created for the page the same as you always do in a template.  You will likely want to render a list of items and, when one of those is clicked, you will then want to render a detail page (if it's a lot of items on the listing page, just return a slice of, perhaps 10, in `get_context()` and add pagination later).  In creating the listing/detail page setup, you could create two separate Wagtail pages - one for a listing of items and another for item detail (for example, a listing of News items and a single page for a single News item).  In this scenario, you would place the detail page in the page tree under the listing page, but set the detail page so that it does not show in the navigation (this is the default setting in the Wagtail admin - it's on the Promote tab).

Two other considerations after you are comfortable with the above:

- You can set things up in the Wagtail admin so that [model entries can be edited there](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) rather than having to edit from the regular Django admin.  Note that the [listing page mentioned in ModelAdmin](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#:%7E:text=customisable%20listing%20pages%20for%20a%20model) is not the same as the listing page mentioned above that you create to be displayed on the website.
- After you are comfortable with displaying data from a database as described with the two-page setup above, you should take a look at the [RoutablePageMixin](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html).  It can provide even more flexibility in how you display items from a database table, and you could even use it to set up a single Wagtail page to display both the listing of items and the detail by having a single template that renders one or the other based upon the context data passed to the template (i.e., you could create two routes on a single Wagtail page - one for the listing and one for the detail).  By doing this, you don't have to have a detail page in the page tree as described above.

Comment: ok i think i will try to use your info ,thanks